# UIPageViewController: how to handle different orientation for view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift2, uipageviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have inherited from UIPageViewContoller class with 3 view controllers. Two from them should have only Portrait orientation and one - all orientations. I added such piece of code:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.currentStackVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return self.currentStackVC.shouldAutorotate()
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return self.currentStackVC.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

}
```

where currentStackVC is current visible view controller.
Also I have such code in my view controllers with a little different implementations:

First two viewcontrollers(next - VC):

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}
```

Last:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}
```

When I located on third view controller - I rotate my device and new orientation applied. But unfortunately it also applied for other VCs. System don't ask shouldAutorotate() in first and second VCs. (As I think because everytime asked only current 3rd VC). I go to second VC(using swipe) and its also in landscape orientation. So, my question is - how can I handle different orientations in Page VC for different screens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

you should use delegate methods of UIPageViewController

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)pageViewControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

For example put this code into UIPageViewController's delegate

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)pageViewControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return [[pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

And override methods in child VCs.

VC1

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

VC2

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for Objective-C. I think it is easy to convert it into swift

Comment: It's ok, Thanks, I will try